# Redirecionar para uma outra URL baseado na URL digitada

Tags: javascript, html, redirecionamento

O meu problema é o seguinte,

Quero adicionar /email a url que foi digitada no browser e redirecionar para essa nova url.
estou usando o IIS do windows server 2012. O site aceita mais de um Host.

Por exemplo no mesmo site eu aceito o host webmail.joao.com.br, webmail.kaina.com.br, webmail.vicor.com.br.

Queria que esse redirecionamento fosse feito adicionando-se "/emailx" ao host que foi digitado e que no endereço nao mostrace o caminho, apenas o que foi digitado originalmente.

Atualmete uso o seguinte codigo, porem só consigo redirecionar para uma unica URL:

```
<frame src="http://webmail.velmo.com.br/MEWebmail" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
```

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt! Por favor, considere especificar mais a sua pergunta e ter cuidado ao atribuir tags para a mesma. Pela falta de clareza na sua dúvida, fica difícil que alguém consiga lhe ajudar da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Olá João, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Por favor, procure fornecer mais detalhes para podermos lhe ajudar melhor. Você falou sobre o servidor ser IIS e a linguagem Java (tag). Você tem certeza que é isso mesmo? Quais tecnologias você tem nesse servidor?

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de mostrar uma outra página dentro do mesmo domínio num frame é alterar o endereço dinamicamente via JavaScript:

Primeiro, defina um endereço em branco e um `id` no `frame`:

```
<frame id="webmail" src="#" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
```

Depois, você pode usar uma função mais ou menos como a seguir para modificar a URL e mudar o `src` do `frame`:

```
function defineFrameUrl(originalUrl) {
  var frame = document.getElementById('webmail');
  if (frame) frame.src = originalUrl + "/emailx";
}
```

E, finalmente, você chama a função passando o endereço atual:

```
defineFrameUrl(window.location.href);
```

Comment: Grato pela atenção, testarei para ver se funciona, porem resolvi apenas com o frame mesmo e sem precisar de script java. <br/>
ao invés de colocar a URL completa 
src="http://webmail.velmo.com.br/MEWebmail"

substitui pelo caminho relativo
src="./MEWebmail" 

isso resolveu, uma vez que o destino esta no mesmo diretório virtual.
desculpe a confusão na minha pergunta original..